# What is the meaning and use of double underscore in aliasing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering about aliasing in MySQL. I saw few interesting things with aliasing. Now I am looking for uses of double underscore (`__`) in MySQL aliasing.

For Example.

```
SELECT emp_name AS New__Name FROM emp;
```

Comment: `_` is just a word character, that could just as easily be `NewName` or `New________Name`; it doesn't have any specific meaning, just legibility for the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about double underscores in MySQL. Some projects use it as a visible separator to distinguish a prefix ([notably PHPMyAdmin](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/628/)), but other than that, it's just a name.